# How to merge distinct and redundant data into one element using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is the input :

```
<Parent>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary1</e4>
  <mName>PRICE</mName>
  <mValue>1234000</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary1</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SPORTS</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC2</e1>
  <e2>QWE</e2>
  <e3>3456</e3>
  <e4>summary2</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SEDAN</mValue>
 </child>
</Parent>
```

I want to merge the child element in such a way that it has both redundant as well as the distinct elements.Below is the expected output,I am not sure how to achieve this using XSL any help appreciated.

Expected output :

```
<Parent>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary</e4>
  <mName>PRICE</mName>
  <mValue>1234000</mValue>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SPORTS</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC2</e1>
  <e2>QWE</e2>
  <e3>3456</e3>
  <e4>summary2</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SEDAN</mValue>
 </child>
</Parent>
```

**Update from comments**

> All the child elements are uniquely
>   identified by 'e1' element. Where two
>   child elements have the same such e
>   elements, they should be merged so
>   there is one child with a list of
>   multiple mName and mValue elements

Comment: Please put your XML inside back quotes (`) so that tags are preserved; these seem to be missing.

Comment: Input XML:`<Parent>
 <child>`
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary1</e4>
  <mName>PRICE</mName>
  <mValue>1234000</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary1</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SPORTS</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC2</e1>
  <e2>QWE</e2>
  <e3>3456</e3>
  <e4>summary2</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SEDAN</mValue>
 </child>
</Parent>`

Comment: Expected output:`<Parent>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary</e4>
  <mName>PRICE</mName>
  <mValue>1234000</mValue>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SPORTS</mValue>
 </child>
 <child>
  <e1>ABC2</e1>
  <e2>QWE</e2>
  <e3>3456</e3>
  <e4>summary2</e4>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SEDAN</mValue>
 </child>
</Parent>`

Comment: I don't think this problem is well defined. Please, specify what should be done that there are pairs of elements that have different sets of children having the same names and values -- which one of the many possible merges should be carried out?

Comment: If you see child1 and child2 has the same redundant data for e1 , e2 e3 , e4 except mName and mValue so I want to merge child1 and child2 in such a way that all the redundant data should remain same but should also have the diff mName and mValue of child1 and child2

Comment: so final child element should look like this:    `<child>
  <e1>ABC1</e1>
  <e2>XYX</e2>
  <e3>4382</e3>
  <e4>summary1</e4>
  <mName>PRICE</mName>
  <mValue>1234000</mValue>
  <mName>TYPE</mName>
  <mValue>SPORTS</mValue>
 </child>`

Comment: It might be better if you fully explained the logic in the question, rather than elaborating on it using comments.

Comment: I'd be wary of the layout of your output- other than the ordering, there's no relationship between the `mName` and `mValue` elements. I'd recommend making this one element `<m Name='' Value='' />` instead. You'll find it easier to work with if you don't have to resort to things like 'following-sibling' to find the `mValue` element associated with the `mName` element.

Answer (score 1):

After much of research and efforts i came up with simpler approach and here is the xsl  which gives desired output '

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="Ids" match="Parent/child" use="e1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Parent">
         <Parent>
            <xsl:for-each select="child[generate-id(.) 
                                        = generate-id(key('Ids', e1)[1])]">
                 <child>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="e1|e2|e3|e4"/>
                     <xsl:for-each select="key('Ids', e1)">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="mName|mValue"/>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                </child >
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Parent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for Muenchian Grouping. You will numerous examples of it within the XSLT tag here on StackOverflow.

I believe what you are saying is that **child** elements are uniquely identified by the elements **e1, e2, e3** and **e4**. Where two **child** elements have the same such **e** elements, they should be merged so there is one **child** with a list of multiple **mName** and **mValue** elements.

First, you need to define a key to help you group the child elements

```
<xsl:key 
   name="children" 
   match="child" 
   use="concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4))))))"/>
```

This creates a key that use the concatenation of the child **e** elements that can be used to look up **child** elements. Do note the use of the pipe character **|** to concatenate them. If any of your elements may contain a pipe character, then you should change this to use another character instead.

Next, you need to match all the occurrences of the first instance of each distinct **child**. This is done with this scary looking statement

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="
     child[generate-id() 
       = generate-id(
         key('children', 
           concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4))))))
         )[1])]"/>
```

i.e Match **child** elements which happen to be the first occurence of that element in our key.

When you have matched the distinct **child** nodes, you can then loop through all other **child** nodes with the same **e** elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('children', concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4)))))))">
```

Putting this altogether gives

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:key name="children" match="child" use="concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4))))))"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Parent">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('children', concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4)))))))[1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="child">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="e1|e2|e3|e4" />
         <xsl:for-each select="key('children', concat(e1, concat('|', concat(e2, concat('|', concat(e3, concat('|', e4)))))))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="mName" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="mValue" />
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply this to your input XML it should give the output you want.

Comment: Thx for the answer Tim but seems like above style sheet is not working , and the assumption is  - all the child elements are uniquely identified by 'e1' element. Where two child elements have the same such e elements, they should be merged so there is one child with a list of multiple mName and mValue elements.

Comment: concat can take multiple arguments, there's no need to nest a bunch of them.

Comment: @SMG: Besides `fn:concat()` style, this is a correct answer **with the information you have provided**. Adding your **new information** to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="childindex" match="child" use="e1" />

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('childindex', e1)[1])]"/>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:variable name="all" select="key('childindex',e1)" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="e1 | e2 | e3 | e4" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$all/mValue | $all/mName" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's a template matching a child node that finds ALL child elements with the same indices, and will output the mValue and mNode elements of all those elements.

The second child template will be applied to any child elements that have a preceding sibling with the same indices, and outputs nothing, stripping out duplicates.

EDIT: Modified the xslt, and the modified version is very similar to Tim's, only the method of populating the child element differs.

Comment: Flynn, I was trying the xsl above but seems like current() can't be applied to match..anyways thx for your answer I'm still researching on the same.

Comment: Works fine when I tried it.. what are you using to process your xslt?

Comment: In a real XSLT 1.0 processor, `fn:current()` can't be used in pattern. It's fine for an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @Alejandro: You're right, never noticed that in the spec. Odd that both Firefox and Chrome will allow it. I've amended the XSLT.